# Alert Message with links to navigate to different scenes in an Swift application

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I need to develop an Alert Message with links to navigate to different scenes in a Swift application.

Please suggest me good techniques or sample codes

Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more ? Alert Message as UIAlertController or something else?

Answer (score 1):

You could implement an alert like so:

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Hi", message: "...", preferredStyle: .Alert)

let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) { (action) in
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SegueTitle", sender: self)
}
alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

let oKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { (action) in
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SegueTitle", sender: self)
}
alertController.addAction(oKAction)

self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true) {
    // ...
}
```